# Cleaner solution to decrementing in for loop

Tags: c

```
for (int x = 0; x < 16; x=x + 5){


    for (int y = x + 4; y >= x; y--){
        printf("The integer is %d\n", y);
    }
}
```

The above code decrements 5 times, then jumps 5 places ahead and repeats the process, so on and so forth.

Is this an acceptable approach to the problem, or is there a cleaner solution, possibly not requiring the nested for loop. It does the job as is, but seems somewhat convoluted.

Output included to demonstrate the required pattern:

```
The integer is 4                                                                                                                 
The integer is 3                                                                                                                 
The integer is 2                                                                                                                 
The integer is 1                                                                                                                 
The integer is 0                                                                                                                 
The integer is 9                                                                                                                 
The integer is 8                                                                                                                 
The integer is 7                                                                                                                 
The integer is 6                                                                                                                 
The integer is 5                                                                                                                 
The integer is 14                                                                                                                
The integer is 13                                                                                                                
The integer is 12                                                                                                                
The integer is 11                                                                                                                
The integer is 10                                                                                                                
The integer is 19                                                                                                                
The integer is 18                                                                                                                
The integer is 17                                                                                                                
The integer is 16                                                                                                                
The integer is 15
```

Comment: I would just make an array with these values in the required order..

Comment: I actually think it is a very clever solution. Why do you want it changed?

Comment: I second @SergeyA - there are alternatives but they're some ugly division/modulo that actually make it harder to reason what's happening.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I used small values for demonstration only. In reality, this will run an indeterminate number of times, depending on other parameters

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I'd be interested in seeing the modulo approach.

Comment: @19172281 divide by 5, multiply by 5 and add 4 - x % 5

Comment: except that the end condition need to be adjusted ofc to 20

Comment: The given code is both the most efficient, and the most readable solution to this problem. There's absolutely no reason to change it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, which solution would you have picked?

Comment: @19172281 your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use modulo and division like this. Note that the boundary must be changed too, otherwise the output will not be identical!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {     
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x ++) {
        printf("The integer is %d\n", x / 5 * 5 + 4 - x % 5);
    }
}
```

If you think the code requires explanation then *your* version is better. At least in my opinion it is.

Comment: Makes sense to me, but yes I agree, definitely harder to understand.